# How can I uniquely Identify facebook user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I get the global facebook link

https://www.facebook.com/5

using v2.2 of facebook API,

Actually my application needs facebook friends and their globally unique facebook ID, I am thinking to get the friend names using `taggable API` but how can I get the unique `facebook ID`? or it is not possible at all ?

If somehow I get this global link for a user, I can extract the global ID

https://www.facebook.com/5

(I know its not possible using their API directly, but there must be some workaround that one can use)

Comment: i´ve answered, but the main question is: what for do you need the global ids of friends?

Comment: that does not answer the question...

Comment: @luschn sorry I mis-read your question, actually I need global IDs as on the basis of these IDs I made specific actions. also I make public calls on the basis of it,

Comment: downvoter please comment as well.

Comment: still not sure what you want to with the ids, that´s pretty vague...what actions exactly? what public calls? for privacy reasons, you are not allowed to do anything with the data anyway, even if you would get it.

Answer (score 2):

**Since v2.0 of the Graph API, you can´t get the global ID or the global link anymore for privacy reasons**. You can only get App Scoped IDs, but those are unique in one App and good enough to detect returning users. Also, you can´t get ALL friends anymore, for anything else than tagging or inviting (which is only available for games with a Facebook Canvas implementation). No App should know about users who don´t even use the App.

`taggable_friends` is for tagging friends only, you are not allowed to use it for anything else and you would need to get it approved by Facebook before going public anyway. And there is no way you would get it approved for anything else.